# Sort array by date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I´m using *sort()* to order an Array by date

```
elements = data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()
});
```

the problem is that some elements are missing the date (or the date is invalid)
and that´s causing this error:

*Cannot read property 'getTime' of **undefined***

update: I have moment ready to use

Where should I check if date is valid date and then use it to order the array?

update: this is the data I have

```
[{
        "date": "2019-06-15 14:57:13",
        "user": "john"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-15 05:48:01",
        "user": "mike"
    },
    {
        "date": "bad-date-format",
        "user": "donna"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-08 10:45:09",
        "user": "Ismil"
    },
    {
        "date": "",
        "user": "Daniel17"
    }
]
```

and this is the output I expect

```
[
    {
        "date": "2019-06-15 14:57:13",
        "user": "john"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-15 05:48:01",
        "user": "mike"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-08 10:45:09",
        "user": "Ismil"
    },
    {
        "date": "bad-date-format",
        "user": "donna"
    },
    {
        "date": "",
        "user": "Daniel17"
    }
]
```

Comment: where do you want to sort items with no or corrupt date?

Comment: order by date descending and the ones with no corrupt data should go at the beginning of the array

Comment: btw, `sort` sorts the array. an assignment takes just the same object reference.

Comment: `a - b` gives ascending order. Do you really mean descending?

Comment: is `getTime` a method of `date` property? please add some data to proof the algorithms of the answers. if your callback works, why do you get a descending result by using the delta of a and b? please add the wanted result as well to the question (and not in comment section).

Comment: done @NinaScholz question updated

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to check if the string is a valid date.

Here's a working code:

```js
const data = [{
        "date": "2019-06-15 14:57:13",
        "user": "john"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-15 05:48:01",
        "user": "mike"
    },
    {
        "date": "bad-date-format",
        "user": "donna"
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-06-08 10:45:09",
        "user": "Ismil"
    },
    {
        "date": "",
        "user": "Daniel17"
    }
];

const elements = data.sort((a, b) => (new Date(b.date).getTime() || -Infinity) - (new Date(a.date).getTime() || -Infinity));
console.log(elements);
```

The trick behind the above code is that `new Date()` will give an `Invalid Date` object if you pass an invalid date string to it, which will return `NaN` if you executed its `getTime()` method.

Now because you want all `Invalid Date`s to be at the bottom, then your sorting function should treat these `Invalid Date`s as the lowest rated in your array, and that's what `-Infinite` means (the lowest number. If you add any number to it will lead to `-Infinite`).

I assume that it doesn't matter how `Invalid Date`s are sorted at the bottom of your array.

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the property exists has the wanted format and then sort the date by string descending and if one has no valid format, take the delta of the boolean values.

```js
function checkDate(string) {
    return typeof string === 'string'
        && /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/.test(string);
}

var array = [{ date: "2019-06-15 14:57:13", user: "john" }, { date: "2019-06-15 05:48:01", user: "mike" }, { date: "bad-date-format", user: "donna" }, { date: "2019-06-08 10:45:09", user: "Ismil" }, { date: "", user: "Daniel17" }];

array.sort((a, b) => {
    var aC = checkDate(a.date),
        bC = checkDate(b.date);

    return aC && bC
        ? b.date.localeCompare(a.date)
        : bC - aC;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: right, it needs an check to prevent the call of the function for not given functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to make sure you have a valid date and when you do for both of your parameters sort them. Otherwise sort the one with the valid date "higher":

```js
let data = [{ "date": "2019-06-15 14:57:13", "user": "john" }, { "date": "2019-06-15 05:48:01", "user": "mike" }, { "date": "bad-date-format", "user": "donna" }, { "date": "2019-06-08 10:45:09", "user": "Ismil" }, { "date": "", "user": "Daniel17" } ]

let result = data.sort((a,b) => Date.parse(a.date) && Date.parse(b.date)
  ? new Date(b.date).getTime() - new Date(a.date).getTime()
  : Date.parse(a.date) ? -1 : 0
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per OPs comment

> order by date descending and the ones with no corrupt data should go at the beginning of the array

```js
let data = [{
  date: new Date('2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
},{
  date: new Date('2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
},{
  date: new Date('2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
}, {}]


function safeGetTime(obj) {
  if (obj && obj.date && obj.date.getTime) {
    return obj.date.getTime();
  }
  return Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; // replace with `return 0` to put invalid data at end of array
}

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return safeGetTime(b) - safeGetTime(a)
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: `let sorted = data.sort(...)` is slightly misleading. `data.sort(...)` sorts `data` in place. `sorted` is not a copy of the data, but simply another reference to the same array.

Comment: Removed `sorted`, force of habit, I mostly keep seperate variables so I can track the flow of data.

Answer (score -1):

```js
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (typeof a.date !== 'undefined' && typeof b.date !== 'undefined') {
      return a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()
    }
    return 0
});
```

**Working simple example**

```js
data = [{date:"100"},{date:null},{date:"1"}, {nodate:"10"}];

data.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (typeof a.date !== 'undefined' && typeof b.date !== 'undefined') {
      return a.date - b.date
    }
    return 0
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Your comparison function doesn't always return a positive/negative/zero number as required by `sort`.

Comment: Now it returns inconsistent results. It's not a valid comparator.

Comment: Also, according to OP, `a.date` is undefined, not `a`

Comment: You can edit the answer, I tried to consider all the comments

Comment: It's not transitive. Imagine you have three elements, `a` with a date of `2000-01-01`, `b` with a date of `null`, `c` with a date of `2000-12-31`. Then your comparison function says that `a == b`, `b == c`, but `a < c`. That's not valid (it violates the [transitivity requirement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)).

Comment: He will leave the result in place, not saying that is a good solution, but it will work.

Comment: Added working example, null gets sorted, undefined stays in place.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `&&` operator.

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.date && b.date && a.date.getTime && b.date.getTime && a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()) || 0
});
```

I would prefer an helper function.

```
const validDate = (...arr) => arr.every(x => x.date && x.date.getTime);
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (validDate(a,b) && a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()) || 0
});
```

Comment: Your comparison function doesn't always return a positive/negative/zero number as required by `sort`.

Comment: Now it returns inconsistent results. It's not a valid comparator.

Comment: @melpomene Sorry can't get what you mean.

Comment: It's not transitive. Imagine you have three elements, `a` with a date of `2000-01-01`, `b` with a date of `null`, `c` with a date of `2000-12-31`. Then your comparison function says that `a == b`, `b == c`, but `a < c`. That's not valid (it violates the [transitivity requirement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)).

Answer (score -2):

You can check before using `getTime`

```js
let data = [{
  date: new Date('2019-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
},{
  date: new Date('2020-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
},{
  date: new Date('2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z')
}, {}]

data.sort((a, b)=>{
  if(!isNaN(new Date(a.date).getTime()) && !isNaN(new Date(b.date).getTime())){
  return a.date.getTime() - b.date.getTime()
  } 
  return Infinity
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Imagine you have three elements, `a` with a date of `2000-01-01`, `b` with a date of `null`, `c` with a date of `2000-12-31`. Then your comparison function says that `a == b`, `b == c`, but `a < c`. That's not valid (it violates the [transitivity requirement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort)).

Comment: @melpomene in that case we can simply filter the falsy value and than sort them ( updated ), i am not how the OP wants the falsy values to be treated

Comment: @CodeManiac this causes data loss of objects without date field;

Comment: As per OPs comment, he wants the data _order by date descending and the ones with no corrupt data should go at the beginning of the array_

Comment: @AyushGupta it's no where mentioned in question to keep the invalid data at start of array

Comment: @CodeManiac There is not need to mention that. Its obvious the length of array should remain same.

Comment: @MaheerAli that certainly depends on how you're using the data,  IMO it's always better to have this added in question itself instead of people having their different opinions on the same thing, i.e let's say i have a data of users and some of them opted for a particular thing and i want to show only the one who opted for particular thing in sorted manner in such cases the length should stay same doesn't makes sense